# Writing Unit test for event handlers C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need a test case for testing event handlers. In my project, I just pass the total file size value from the `Model` class to `ViewModel` class using event handlers.

What are all the ways to write test case for event handlers and what I have to do in my test case?

My test case is not working..

### View Model

```
public RipWatcherWindowShellViewModel(IWorkflowManager workflowManager)
{
    WorkflowManager = workflowManager;
    workflowManager.GetTotalUsfFileSize += workflowManager_GetTotalFileSize;
}


/// <summary>Delegate for workflowManager get total file size</summary>
/// <param name="sender">The sender object</param>
/// <param name="e">The FileSizeChangedEventArgs object</param>
public void workflowManager_GetTotalFileSize(object sender, FileSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.FileSize== 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("We cannot calculate progress percentage because total file size is 0");
    }
    TotalUsfFileSize = e.FileSize;
}
```

### Model

```
public class WorkflowManager
{

    public event EventHandler<FileSizeChangedEventArgs> GetTotalUsfFileSize;

    public void StartWorkflow()
    {           
        totalFileSize= jobWatcher.StartWatching(HotFoldersCollection);

         //Event handler Raised here....

        GetTotalUsfFileSize.SafeInvoke(this, new FileSizeChangedEventArgs(totalFileSize));
     }
  }
```

### Event Handler

```
public class FileSizeChangedEventArgs:EventArgs
{

    public FileSizeChangedEventArgs (Double fileSize)
    {
        FileSize = fileSize;
    }

    public Double FileSize
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

### My Test case

```
[Test]
public void IsGetTotalFileSizeEventFired()
{
    worflowManager = new Mock<IWorkflowManager>().Object;

    ripWatcherWindowShellViewModel = new RipWatcherWindowShellViewModel(worflowManager);
    ripWatcherWindowShellViewModel.GetTotalUsfFileSize += delegate { eventRaised = true; };

    Assert.IsTrue(eventRaised);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? Where are you raising the event?

Comment: You need something after the `ripWatcherWindowShellViewModel.TransferredFileSize += ...` that causes the event to be raised.

Comment: I think you need to separate EventHandler and "buisness" logic. Create a method in the ViewModel which takes file size as parameter. And write test for that method. For EventHandler enough to test that event was raised and your handler executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing that your event handler works, simply call the event handler with the event args that you want to test.

In your case I assume you want to test that your event is raised. This will be dependent on if any calls inside your `StartWorkFlow` have any external dependencies (like to the actual file system. If it does, then you are crossing over into integration test territory and no longer unit test territory). In that instance, make sure `jobWatcher` is also mocked, or make `StartWorkFlow` virtual so that you can alter its behavior to suit your test.